# For what collection types does the C# compiler generate collection classes?

Tags: c#, collections

[The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-5.0#performance-considerations) for `List<T>` states:

> If a value type is used for type `T`, the compiler generates an implementation of the `List<T>` class specifically for that value type. That means a list element of a `List<T>` object does not have to be boxed before the element can be used...

A question was raised in the comments about exactly what "the compiler" refers to here. That's tangential to the question, which is about what else "the compiler" (whatever that may mean) does this to.

Is this true of any other collection type? If it's only `List<T>`, is it good practice to always use `List<T>` for value types even when some other collection like `Queue<T>` better expresses your intent?

Comment: it would be true for all collection types that take generic type parameter

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Is that documented anywhere? Or perhaps do other collections use `List<T>` internally?

Comment: I would suggest that you should always use the type that best fits your need rather than worry about wether they are value types or not. So if you need a queue, use `Queue<T>`

Comment: As @EhsanSajjad mentions this is not specific to `List<T>` - [this is true for any generic type definition with a type parameter that accepts value types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generics-in-the-run-time)

Comment: I read the docs like so: Generic collections use the specified type for your items. Non-generic collections must cast all items to `object` which will require boxing for value types.

Comment: What you ask in the question is not true of the C# compiler *at all* (which is probably why it is getting downvoted - you're asking a follow-up question where the premise is wrong); the JIT compiler (which happens at a very different time) does this, but *when* depends on the specific `T` - for example, for all reference-type `T`, the implementation is pretty much *common between all of them*. Nothing is specific about `List<T>` vs `Queue<T>`. Basically, the documentation is speaking in a rather broad, loose sense.

Comment: @MarcGravell Can you reconcile your assertion that this is "not true of the compiler at all" with my direct quote from the documentation that "the compiler generates..."?

Comment: @Tech define "the compiler". I said that the C# compiler doesn't do this, which is true. I also said that the JIT compiler *does*. These are different things. You asked about the C# compiler, which has no part in this. Run it through ildasm to see. But: you asked about the C# compiler, which again: *doesn't do any such thing*. To reconcile: to repeat myself, the docs are being vague and wooly.

Comment: @MarcGravell If you think "the compiler" in the official documentation means something other than the compiler, then interpret my question as being about whatever you think "the compiler" means. Exactly what is doing it is not really relevant to the substance of the question. The question is about *what else it (whatever it is) does the same thing to.* And that was answered in a comment.

Comment: @Tech again, I tried to be as clear as possible that I was disambiguating between the C# compiler (that you asked about), and other steps. There is no single "the compiler", regardless of what those docs say. If they're misleading: hit the feedback button on the docs page; I didn't write them, and I can't comment on why they're not quite what you want.

Comment: @MarcGravell Again, exactly what those docs mean by "the compiler" is **totally irrelevant to my question.**

Comment: @Tech you've asked about those docs and what they say about "the compiler", but sure: if you say that what those docs mean about "the compiler" is irrelevant - fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: use the most appropriate generic type that expresses your intent. `Queue<T>` is just fine if you want to represent a queue, for example.

---

Longer answer: quite honestly: that documentation is vague. When it mentions "the compiler", it isn't talking about the C# (build-time) compiler (which translates C# to IL), but rather to the JIT (runtime) compiler, which translates IL to CPU instructions (appropriately for your specific CPU and environment).

The feature it is using here is simply a feature of generics, which applies equally to any generic usage; it isn't specific to `List<T>` - the same ideas apply to any `<T>` type (or multi-generic-parameter types, too), including arrays.

The docs are also ... a little wooly and imprecise. The details *probably don't really matter to most people*, but it doesn't really do this per-T; or at least, not all T. Every value-type T (or permutation involving value-types, for multi-generic-parameter scenarios) gets a bespoke JIT, but all the reference-type T **share** a single implementation. This is tied to the fact that only value-type usages involve boxing, and that boxing is per-T; for reference-type usages, a type check is sufficient. And even for value-type scenarios, often the box step can be avoided via "constrained" calls.

---

If I was trying to be generous: the document is perhaps trying to contrast against non-generic collections (which you shouldn't really be using in %current year%), in a way that might make sense to someone more familiar with .NET 1.1; in doing so, they're... very far from precise.